# Encode URL in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to encode an URL created by the `{% url %}` template tag in order to pass it as an argument in an iframe src which generates a Facebook Like button.

What's an appropriate way to do this? The `urlencode` template filter doesn't seem to work here. My template code looks like this:

```
{% url blog_urls/blog_detail slug=p.slug year=p.published_on.year month=p.published_on.month day=p.published_on.day %}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `url` tag takes another argument which allows you to create a variable with the value of the url:

```
{% url foo bar=baz as my_url %}
{{ my_url|filters }}}
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe i overlooked that one!

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you can always use the filter tag itself to apply filters to more complex tags, eg:

```
{% filter urlencode %}{% url blog_urls/blog_detail slug=p.slug year=p.published_on.year month=p.published_on.month day=p.published_on.day %}{% endfilter %}
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#filter